# jQuery page scroll not working since update

Tags: jquery

For some reason my page scroll has stopped working. It works perfectly on my home page but when I navigate to a different page and then click 'About' for instance it directs me back to the home page but fails to scroll up to the #About section. I hope that makes sense. Here is my code:

```
 <script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
&& location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 200 //offsets for fixed header
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  if($(location.href.split("#")[1])) {
      var target = $('#'+location.href.split("#")[1]);
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 200 //offset height of header here too.
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
});
</script>
```

The only change I have made is the 'a[href*=\#]:not([href=\#])', Chrome was throwing a fit and stating an UnCaught error type but I don't think that is the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a few questions. Do you have reload of the page, when you click on the navigation? If yes, is this script executed there? Is your click event even triggered after you change the page?

Comment: It doesn't trigger when I change the page but it works on home page. I added console.log("Fired!"); works perfectly until I click from one page back to the home page.